# TypeScript not finding variable declared in type declaration if I import a file

Tags: typescript

I made a very simple library which contains a `.d.ts` ([source](https://gitlab.com/Telokis/embed-i18n-webpack-plugin/-/blob/master/src/index.d.ts)) which has the following structure (I omit the details because the file works fine, it likely is a config issue in my project):

```
// Some helper types and interfaces

type TranslationFunction = /* ... */;

export { TranslationFunction };
```

Then, I do `npm i -D embed-i18n-webpack-plugin` to install the package into my own project and create a file `typings/translation.d.ts` to declare a global `t` variable of type `TranslationFunction` like follow:

```
import { TranslationFunction } from "embed-i18n-webpack-plugin";

declare const t: TranslationFunction;
```

Using VSCode, I can hover over `t` in this file and it tells me that it has the proper type as defined in my original `index.d.ts`. This means that when I'm in this file, it properly finds it.

In this same `typings` directory, I have some other files declaring constants but they never import anything and work as expected.

However, when I try to use the global `t` function inside my code, I get an error stating

`Cannot find name 't'. ts(2304)`

BUT if I simply comment the import inside my `typings/translation.d.ts`:

```
// import { TranslationFunction } from "embed-i18n-webpack-plugin";

declare const t: TranslationFunction;
```

It works fine but since it doesn't know `TranslationFunction`, it collapses into `any`.

Maybe the type declaration file of my package is wrong and should contain some `declare module`? I'm not really 100% sure of the behavior when it comes to publishing type declarations on npm, I usually use them in plain TS so it works fine. It's the first time I use one inside another type declaration file.

In case it might be relevant, here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noEmit": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "strictFunctionTypes": false,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "target": "esnext",
        "extendedDiagnostics": true,
        "paths": {
            "$common/*": ["../Common/*"],
            "$config": ["./config"],
            "$game/*": ["./src/game/*"],
            "$containers/*": ["./src/containers/*"],
            "$phaser/*": ["./src/phaser/*"],
            "$network/*": ["./src/network/*"],
            "$pages/*": ["./src/pages/*"],
            "$components/*": ["./src/components/*"],
            "$helpers/*": ["./src/helpers/*"],
            "$rematch/*": ["./src/rematch/*"],
            "$hooks/*": ["./src/hooks/*"],
            "$types/*": ["./src/types/*"],
            "$src/*": ["./src/*"]
        },
        "rootDir": ".",
        "baseUrl": "."
    },
    "exclude": ["**/node_modules/*", "build", "coverage"]
}
```

Finally, I have tried some things to see if that would solve my issue:

- Copying the content of my package's type declaration inside my `typings/translate.d.ts` --> Works fine
- Adding some random `declare module "ember-i18n-webpack-plugin` --> Same error

Comment: can you give an example of how you're trying to use this? Are you saying that you're trying to use your const t in a different file as though it's a global or in the same file where it's declared?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the question my goal is to declare and use it as a global in my whole project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

importing into declaration files and making them globally available is a little weird, looks like this:

```
declare const t: import("embed-i18n-webpack-plugin").TranslationFunction;
```

That should be all you need to do to. Typescript won't register a declaration as global if it has traditional imports in it, so you need to use this import style. this does require typescript version >= 2.9

docs on it:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#import-types

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't solve the issue. `t` is still reported as not found by TypeScript. Using `export` in declaration files is not very relevant if I'm not declaring a module or adding type for a js file.

Comment: It could be relevant depending on how you’re trying to use this... are you just trying to avoid writing import statements? An example of how you’re attempting to use this global would be helpful.

Comment: I use this global variable by doing `t(arg1, arg2)`. `import` does not make sense because the function is a meta function which is totally removed by webpack when compiling the source files.

Comment: oookk I was unclear on what you were after but i took a look at the repo and I get it now... updated answer...

Comment: Ok it's the first time I see this style of import inside a declaration file! It works fine, I accepted your answer but could you edit your answer to add a source to the documentation regarding this behavior, please? Thanks for solving my (strange) issue!